# Confusion in understanding of unique subgroup of $\langle a \rangle$ with order $k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

> **Theorem:** Every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic. Moreover, if $| \langle a \rangle|=n$, then the order of any subgroup of $\langle a \rangle$ is a divisor of $n$; and , for each positive divisor $k$ of $n$, the  group $\langle a \rangle$ has exactly one subgroup of order $k$- namely $\langle a^{\frac{n}{k}}\rangle$.

I have confusion, in understanding of uniqueness. For example: in $\mathbb Z_6$ there are two subgroups of order $6$ - namely $\langle 1 \rangle$ and $\langle 5 \rangle$ - and $3$  - namely $\langle 2 \rangle $ and $\langle 4 \rangle$.
But according to theorem $\langle 2 \rangle$ and $\langle 1 \rangle$ must be unique subgroups of order $3$ and $6$ respectively.
I don't know where my understanding lacks. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

**Edit**: Precisely the lack in my understanding was that $\langle 5 \rangle$ and $\langle 1 \rangle$ are different subgroups of order 6. But I now understand that theorem says " In a cyclic group $\langle a \rangle$ there is only one subgroup of order $k$, that is $\{e,a,a^2,...,a^{k-1}\}$. Now if any other subgroup of $\langle a \rangle$ has order k then the subgroup is nothing else but above set(subgroup). Having different generator doesn't make different set (subgroup)". Sorry for my dumb question. Before posting the question I was feeling the notion is like above (which i explained now), but I was not able to precisely explain it to myself so i thought there is lack of my knowledge/understanding thats why i post.

Comment: $<1>$ and $<5>$ have order 6, namely they are the whole group.

Comment: @citadel Corrected the typo.

Comment: The uniqueness does not concern the particular *generator* of the (sub)group, but of a certain order (cardinality if you will).

Comment: @NickyHekster My understanding: To find counter-example of the uniqueness i have two find two subgroups of same order and different elements. Having different generator and having different elements in subgroup (set) are two different things. Because some subgroup have more than one generators. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: In $\Bbb Z_6$ we have $5 = -1$ so $5\Bbb Z = -\Bbb Z = \Bbb Z;\,$ similarly $\,4 = -2\,$ so $\,4\Bbb Z = -2\Bbb Z = 2\Bbb Z\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque so $\langle 5 \rangle = \langle -1 \rangle = \langle 1 \rangle$ are nothing but different names of the set $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ which has order 6? It means every subgroup having order 6 in $ ℤ _6$ is only $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ . Like this ?

Comment: Yes, exactly @Afzal. I think that explicitly writing set-wise the subgroup makes convicing about its uniqueness, irrespective of the generator used for its "compact" representation.

Answer (score 0):

<2> and <4> are not different subgroup,
<1> and <5> are not different subgroup of **Z_6**.
They are same.

Comment: Please try to explain things in your answers, rather than simply making claims.

Comment: In Z_6, <2>={ [2], [4], [6] } and  <4>={ [4], [8]=[2], [12]= [6] }